# FFMPEG vstack and loop

Tags: loops, ffmpeg, stack

I would like to stack 4 videos as in the code below and **add a loop** for top_left.mp4 that is shorter for example.
I can't find a way to add the loop option without getting errors. 
Could you help me please?

```
ffmpeg -i top_left.mp4 -i top_right.mp4 -i bottom_left.mp4 -i bottom_right.mp4 \ 
       -lavfi "[0:v][1:v]hstack[top];[2:v][3:v]hstack[bottom];[top][bottom]vstack" \
        2by2grid.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-stream_loop -1` and add `shortest=1` to the first [hstack](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hstack):

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i top_left.mp4 -i top_right.mp4 -i bottom_left.mp4 -i bottom_right.mp4 -lavfi "[0:v][1:v]hstack=shortest=1[top];[2:v][3:v]hstack[bottom];[top][bottom]vstack" 2by2grid.mp4
```

[xstack](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#xstack) version:

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i top_left.mp4 -i top_right.mp4 -i bottom_left.mp4 -i bottom_right.mp4 -lavfi "[0][1][2][3]xstack=inputs=4:layout=0_0|w0_0|0_h0|w0_h0:shortest=1" 2by2grid.mp4
```

Comment: how do you specify which video as the shortest in the xstack version?

Comment: @Richard You don't need to specify which video is the shortest. It will automatically make the output the same duration as the shortest input.

Comment: I was hoping I could get the output the same duration as the longest input rather than the shortest, or the same duration of a video of my choice. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @Richard You can use the tpad + adelay/apad filters to extend the shorter videos. Or loop them. Or use trim/atrim filters to limit lengths. Should be plenty of example answers here. Search `[ffmpeg] is:answer tpad`